# could not initialize android widget error

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm a complete beginner in android, and eclipse so forgive me if my question is too easy.
My problem is I can't find the working area in the graphical layout tab. And it gives me an error whenever i try to change it to landscape or portrait.

here is my eclipse:[image]

I want to make this show, so i can layout my application easily.
[image]

my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.androidproject.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try changing the theme to AppTheme ... or did you tried cleaning you project

Comment: @Darkie - not working bro.

Comment: did you tried these answers ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495941/xml-error-in-eclipse-while-viewing-graphical-layout-of-xml

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437776/xml-error-in-eclipse-after-updating-android-sdk-tools

Comment: @Darkie - yes i tried the first one, and it didn't work. the second one isn't related to my problem.